# Open Javascript Id on a new window

Tags: javascript

Am trying to open an id on a new window, this is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).parent().data("url"),
            data: { callNumber: $(this).parent().data("callno") },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#CallDetail").html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When i click .myButton class it opens the id:

```
 <div id="CallDetail"></div>
```

thats located on the home page.

What i need is to open on a new window, i have tried doing this via the link :

```
<div data-callno='@parts.Call_Num' data-url="@Url.Action("GetCallInfo", "CallHandling" , new {target = "_blank"})">
 <div class="myButton toolbarIcon">
  <div class="toolbarIconText">View</div>
</div>
```

But no luck, at the moment it just opens in the same page i am doing this, the problem is am getting data called in the JavaScript so its trickier then i imagined. any ideas?

Comment: Is `#CallDetail` contained in the returned HTML?

Comment: yes. this works but and shows the id when i click then link, but i want to open this in a new page... i have tried window,locate but that doesnt get the data

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'open this in a new page'? You can use `window.open(url, '_blank');` to programatically open a link in a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to search the returned HTML for a selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).parent().data("url"),
            data: { callNumber: $(this).parent().data("callno") },
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find('#CallDetail');
            },
        });
    });
});
```